# How to play audio from RTMP stream?

Tags: audio, rtmp, aac

I'm working with RTMP. I have captured RTMP packents in wireshark. I know how to assemble and play video data but don't know how to play audio.  Wireshark  tell me that data is in .aac. But i don't get how i can play it? Is i need to wrap it in container? [wireshark capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4hx1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AAC can be played without a container. But every frame must have an ADTS header (google can explain that part to you) to convert from raw frames to ADTS you must get the sequence header from the start of the stream and convert to ADTS.

Comment: Thank you again for your reply.

Comment: But i think there is something else. From the start of the stream i receive small part of audio data(0x00 0x14 0x08 ). And each block after this data start with bytes 0x01 0x01. Perhaps there is another way to play data or I'm wrong ?

Comment: I think that 0x00 - is type, and 0x1408 is AAC Configuration. Then 0x1408 -> 0001 0100 0000 1000.
00010 - 5 bits for object type.(AAC low complexity)
1000 - 4 bits for sampling rate
0001 - 4 bit for channel
0 -  bit for frame length flag 
0 - bit for depends on core coder
0 - bit for depends on core coder

Comment: Nope, nothing else. Just make sure you are not writing the packet type byte (that is part of the flv tag, and not part of the aac payload) and don't write the sequence header to the file, just convert it to an ADTS header and write that before every frame. You don't even need to parse the frame.

Comment: Thank. It's my first experience in this area and it a little difficult to understand all this details.

Comment: I need use fixed ADTS header and variable ADTS header. Or only fixed?

Comment: I parsed aac sequence  and get this info:
00010 - AAC LC, 1000 - 1600Hz, 0001 - 1channel, 0 - frame len 1024, 0, 0 . Then i convert into ADTS header ( ff f1 60 40 20 3f fc ). My packet size is 250 + 7(header). But when i try to play it doesn't work. Whats i do wrong?